# ATG- Issue in sending email through utility java scheduler

Tags: java, smtp, atg

In ATG i got below exception, when `this.getSmtpEmailSender().sendEmailMessage(msg)` method called. But same code working fine with different environment. May be it configuration issue. what i need to check.

```
/com/ncr/base/common/services/EmailService      

java.lang.Exception: The final format argument for a vlog call is a throwable, but is not referenced. The throwable will be logged, but please use an explicit Throwable argument before the format string to eliminate ambiguity.

**** Warning    Fri Dec 21 02:49:02 -05:00 2018 1545378542129   /com/ncr/base/common/services/EmailService              at atg.nucleus.logging.VariableArgumentApplicationLoggingUtil.getUnreferencedThrowable(VariableArgumentApplicationLoggingUtil.java:744)
**** Warning    Fri Dec 21 02:49:02 -05:00 2018 1545378542129   /com/ncr/base/common/services/EmailService              at atg.nucleus.logging.VariableArgumentApplicationLoggingUtil.vlogError(VariableArgumentApplicationLoggingUtil.java:344)
```

/com/ncr/base/common/services/EmailService        nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 5.1.7 Invalid address

Comment: _501 5.1.7 Invalid address_ means that the mail server rejected the message because of an invalid address from the sender or the addressee. Without more information we can't possibly help to identify exactly what.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is one of your email addresses is not valid in either the `To` or `From` fields.

ATG allows you to configure defaults for the `/atg/dynamo/service/SMTPEmail/` components and I think that you are missing a configuration for the environment in question.  I would recommend you open dyn/admin and compare the configuration for SMTP email for environments which are working vs ones which are not.